# flex box with images in a row

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap panel to display three images in a row. Suppose if I have six images in total, I want to display three in a row and the next three should come one by one as I move the scrollbar.

For applying the scrollbar, I did `overflow-x:visible`, but nothing is coming on the screen.

Also, the fourth image is coming below the three images in a row.

What should I do to make the images horizontally scrollable with three images getting displayed on the screen at a time?

The codepen link to my code is: [Link](https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/RgQwMd)

Comment: What does _"come one by one"_ mean? Can you include your [mcve] _in the question itself_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 225px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x50/000000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x50/ff0000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x50/333333">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x50/00ff00">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x50/666666">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x50/0000ff">
</div>
```